# After several times of ipmitool commands, now I can not get established with IPMI address using ipmitool now

Tags: ipmi

I created a VM CentOS 7(based on a Dedicated Server), installed the `ipmitool` in it, I want to use it to manage the Dedicated Servers under the LAN(172.18.16.0/20), now in the VM I can ping `172.18.16.230`(one Dedicated Server's IPMI address).

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 172.18.16.230
PING 172.18.16.230 (172.18.16.230) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.18.31.252: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 172.18.16.230)
From 172.18.31.252 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Network64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.15 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.16 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.16 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.17 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=2.17 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=2.17 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.21 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.23 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.24 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=1.24 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=1.24 ms (DUP!)
From 172.18.31.252: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 172.18.16.230)
From 172.18.31.252 icmp_seq=3 Redirect Network64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.68 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=2.45 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=2.48 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=2.92 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 172.18.16.230: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=2.93 ms (DUP!)
```

before, I can get power status of it by using command:

```
ipmitool -H 172.18.16.230 -I lanplus -U ADMIN -P ADMIN power status
```

after several times' usage of the command(works fine), but I can not establish session with it at now:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ipmitool -H 172.18.16.230 -I lanplus -U ADMIN -P ADMIN power status
Error: Received an Unexpected Open Session Response
Error: Received an Unexpected Open Session Response
Error: Received an Unexpected Open Session Response
Error: Received an Unexpected Open Session Response
Error: Received an Unexpected Open Session Response
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session
```

I don't know why I can not get status now, but in the first times it works fine, and I did nothing else about the configuration.

---

**EDIT-01**

the VM is based on a dedicated server, VM bridging to the dedicated server physical interfaces.

The bellow is my arping:

```
[ldl@localhost network-scripts]$ arping -b -I eno16777736 172.18.16.230
ARPING 172.18.16.230 from 172.18.31.249 eno16777736
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.126ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  2.172ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.322ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.172ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.076ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.275ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.314ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.314ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.558ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.301ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.266ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.269ms
Unicast reply from 172.18.16.230 [AC:1F:6B:A6:B6:EF]  1.263ms
^CSent 13 probes (13 broadcast(s))
Received 13 response(s)
```

the VM's ipmi manage ip is `172.18.31.249/20`.

Comment: Are you sure 172.18.16.230 is _one_ server's IPMI address? The `ping` output makes it look like you have at least five different devices trying to use the same address. Can you `arping -b -I eth0 172.18.16.230` if you're on the same subnet?

Comment: @grawity see my edit-01, they are under the subnet, there is no gateway, they all are `/20`.